# Waiting for User Input - Javascript

Tags: javascript, listener, sleep

I am currently working on a webapp for a two player game where the players can be either human players or AI. For each player, I am using a class which is either Human or AI and extends an Agent class.

```
class Agent{
    ... 
    getMove(){...}
}
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
while(!gameOver){
    move = curAgent.getMove(); 
    updateBoard(move);
    nextPlayer();
}
```

Then, for the human agent class I am struggling to come up with a getMove function. Human players will provide moves by clicking on the board. This is what I am currently trying and it doesn't appear to work.

```
class Human extends Agent{
    ...
    getMove(){
        while(!flag){
            sleep(500);
        }
        flag = false;
        return this.move;
    }


    listener(){
        this.move = ... //when square clicked set move 
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

I tried using setInterval or setTimeout, but since they are non-blocking the functions return immediately and the main while loop fails. Any help would be much appreciated. Is there a way to restructure the logic to avoid this issue?

Comment: Can you use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and have your main loop await user input?

Comment: There's not a lot of context here, but assuming this will run in a browser, you should use event listeners to detect when the user has interacted in certain ways. Synchronously blocking the script will result in a horrible user experience - Javascript makes this hard for a reason!

Comment: @MikeSamuel Could you elaborate a bit more on how that might work?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I suspect that my logic for the main while(!gameOver) loop is flawed and there is a better way of implementing this in javascript. From what I've read, running the game synchronously requires me to block when waiting for user input. However, I am not familiar enough with javascript to know how to approach an asynchronous implementation.